# AppHarbor not deploying web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor

I have an app on AppHarbor that originally started with a single background worker. I have recently updated it to include an MVC4 web site and have updated the subscription to 2 workers.

After I have deployed the application, if I go to the host name (myapp.apphb.com, not the real hostname) I get the "Welcome to nginx!" page.

The build logs shows that is deploying worker.1.

7/31/13 11:12 AM    Received notification, queuing build
7/31/13 11:12 AM    Downloading source
7/31/13 11:12 AM    Downloaded source in 2.77 seconds
7/31/13 11:12 AM    Starting build
7/31/13 11:12 AM    0 warnings
7/31/13 11:12 AM    Build completed in 19.87 seconds
7/31/13 11:12 AM    Starting website precompilation 
7/31/13 11:12 AM    Precompilation completed in 10.73 seconds
7/31/13 11:12 AM    Starting tests
7/31/13 11:12 AM    Tests completed in 2.59 seconds 
7/31/13 11:12 AM    Deploying worker.1
7/31/13 11:12 AM    Pre-warming worker
7/31/13 11:12 AM    Build successfully deployed

By looking over the log session worker.1 looks to be the background worker and there is no mention of the web application.

The subscription clearly shows 1 web worker and 1 background worker.

So it seems like the deploy process is not recognizing there is a web app to deploy.

Comment: AppHarbor support is very effective and responsive. I think you should try them

Answer (score 0):

I ended up knocking the subscription down to 1 web worker and redeployed and it picked up and deployed ok.

Bumping the subscription back to 2 workers (1 web, 1 background) brought both workers online.